# Show two image one in android above another image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom grid view for each and every grid I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="85sp"
    android:background="@drawable/shelf" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgThumb"
    android:layout_width="47.5sp"
    android:layout_height="76sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29sp"
    android:background="@drawable/pic1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bookCover"
    android:layout_width="60sp"
    android:layout_height="80sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="127sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26sp"
    android:background="@drawable/book_cover" />
```

**which looks like this before Graphical layout in eclipse** [image]

**but when I am running this on emulator  it looks like**
[image]

Book cover image is gone I am new in android please don't where is the problem and how to solve it

** FrameLayout is also not working**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/shelf" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgThumb"
    android:layout_width="47.5sp"
    android:layout_height="76sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29sp"
    android:background="@drawable/pic1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bookCover"
    android:layout_below="@id/imgThumb"
    android:layout_width="60sp"
    android:layout_height="80sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="127sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26sp"
    android:background="@drawable/book_cover" />
```

So your background will be shown. And orientation will not come in RelativeLayout.

Comment: not possible I need to put 

    `android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="85sp"` 

inside @drawable/shelf viewtag

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dummy"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pitch"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/pic1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
                android:background="@drawable/book_cover" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```